# (Mongo/Mongoose) How to handle waiting for the result of multiple queries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord

I'm writing a Discord bot that generates weekly Guild stats for text and voice channel usage. My code divides several Mongo queries up into separate methods:

```
function getTopActiveTextChannels() {
  let topTextChannels = []
  ChannelModel.find({}).sort({"messageCountThisWeek": -1}).limit(topLimit)
   .exec(channels => {
    channels.forEach(c => {
      topTextChannels.push({"name": c.name, "messageCount": c.messageCount})
    })
    console.log(topTextChannels)
    return topTextChannels
  })
}

function getTopActiveVoiceMembers() {
  let topVoiceMembers = []
  UserModel.find({}).sort({"timeSpentInVoice": -1}).limit(topLimit)
  .exec(users => {
    users.forEach(u => {
      topVoiceMembers.push({"username": u.username, "timeSpentInVoice": u.timeSpentInVoice})
    })
    console.log(topVoiceMembers)
    return topVoiceMembers
  })
}
```

I then have one method that calls both those and (for now) prints the values to console:

```
function getWeeklyGuildStats(client) {
  let topActiveTextChannels = getTopActiveTextChannels()
  let topVoiceMembers = getTopActiveVoiceMembers()
  let promisesArray = [topActiveTextChannels, topVoiceMembers]

  Promise.all(promisesArray).then(values => {console.log(values)})
}
```

Executing `getWeeklyGuildStats(client)` outputs: `[ undefined, undefined ]`. I am sure I'm not using promises correctly, but when I follow Mongoose's documentation, it tells me to use `exec()` instead of `then()`, but I get a `channels = null` error with that.

Does anything jump out to anyone? This seems like a fairly common pattern. Does anyone have a solution for how to resolve multiple Mongoose queries in a single method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` should take an array of promises, while your functions are returning normal array, so you need to return the whole query in the helper method which getting the users and channels, then do your logic after the `promise.all`

your functions may look something like that

```
function getTopActiveTextChannels() {
  return ChannelModel.find({}).sort({"messageCountThisWeek": -1}).limit(topLimit).exec();
}

function getTopActiveVoiceMembers() {
  return UserModel.find({}).sort({"timeSpentInVoice": -1}).limit(topLimit).exec();
}
```

then the function that calls these two methods will be something like

```
function getWeeklyGuildStats(client) {
  let topActiveTextChannels = getTopActiveTextChannels()
  let topVoiceMembers = getTopActiveVoiceMembers()
  let promisesArray = [topActiveTextChannels, topVoiceMembers]

  Promise.all(promisesArray).then(values => {
     console.log(values);
     // here you could do your own logic, the for loops you did in the helper methods before
  });
}
```

Comment: OK, modified the parameters to `Promise.all()` to be method invocations. Still getting the output `[ undefined, undefined ]`

Comment: could you try to console.log the users and channels once the queries have been done? I meant to log the users after .then in getTopActiveVoiceMembers function and the same for channels?

Comment: I added `console.log` statements before the return values for each method. Both `topTextChannels` and `topVoiceMembers` are printing the correct data.

Comment: I've edited my answer, could you check it now?, hope it helps now

Comment: I've reorganized my lookup methods to return the Mongoose promise and moved the `.then()` logic to separate helper methods, which I call from the main method. Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any return statements in the root level of your functions, so they are always *synchronously* returning `undefined`. I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but if for example `ChannelModel.find({}).exec(callback)` returns a promise with the return value of `callback` as your code implies, then you just need to add a `return` statement to your functions.

For example:

```js
function getTopActiveTextChannels() {
  let topTextChannels = []
  // Return this! (Assuming it returns a promise.) Otherwise you're always returning `undefined`.
  return ChannelModel.find({}).sort({"messageCountThisWeek": -1}).limit(topLimit)
   .exec(channels => {
    channels.forEach(c => {
      topTextChannels.push({"name": c.name, "messageCount": c.messageCount})
    })
    console.log(topTextChannels)
    return topTextChannels
  })
}
```